# PrintStream - how to write inside an already created file

Tags: java, printstream

I want to write the results of my tests to an already created text file using `PrintStream`. Unfortunately i only know about this statement

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Results.txt"))
```

but this is creating a new file. Removing `new` from the statement won't work.

So, what is the command to write in `Results.txt` without deleting the previous results/creating a new one?

Comment: Do you mean you want to append the data to the end of the file?

Answer (score 7):

Use this constructor to open the file in append mode :

```
public FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
```

i.e.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Results.txt",true));
```

Comment: Thanks man! That was what i was looking for!